# Freeze top row in a SharePoint 365 list

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to freeze the top row in my SP list, but everything I read involves coding and I am not a programmer. Has SP added this as a feature and if so, how do I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Sticky Column Headers" is implemented for large lists only according to the roadmap here -> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=SharePoint#owRoadmapMainContent

Excerpt:

> Sticky column headers For large lists and libraries, the column headers will remain visible as you scroll vertically or horizontally in larger lists and libraries. More info Featured ID: 46103 Added to Roadmap: 1/24/2019 Last Modified: 6/25/2019 Tags: SharePoint

and this blog post here -> https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-SharePoint-Blog/January-2019-SharePoint-Modernization-News/ba-p/320552

> Sticky Headers
>   Coming in March 2019.  Libraries and lists can get extremely large – up to 30 million items in a single list.  Soon, as you scroll down through ever-larger lists, SharePoint keeps the column headers pinned at the top of the scrolling window.  This helps you identify list values as you move vertically and horizontally through the view.  Column headers will also remain in place inside the list/library web parts.

Comment: This seems to work  in regular lists, but not in Quick edit or datasheet view. How can I get it to work in datasheet view or quick edit?

Comment: As of October 2019 this is still not available in Quick Edit/Datasheet. You could add your vote to the requests to add it on this user voice -> https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/16077640-freeze-column-headers